# Fix for CRM On Demand error SBL-ODU-01006

Tags: web-services, crm, siebel, ondemand

I am trying to access the CRM On Demand WebService through SOAPUI Client

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns="urn:crmondemand/ws/account/10/2004" xmlns:acc="urn:/crmondemand/xml/account">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken
            xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'>
            <wsse:Username>compID/username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password
                Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>mypassword</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>

<soapenv:Body>
<!-- some query parameters  -->
</soapenv:Body>
```

And the server is responding with

```
<ErrorCode>SBL-ODU-01006</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorMessage>Unknown user sign in ID or password. Make sure your CapsLock key is off, and try again.</ErrorMessage>
```

Could you please point out what I am doing wrong ? Many thanks.

Comment: any success with this. having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you wrote the contents of the `Header` tag yourself.

In `soapUI` you don't have to do so.

Instead, for each request you set (among other options) your credentials and authorization method (`WSS-Password Type`) and `soapUI` will generate a correct security header for you.

It may be clearer if you look at the annotated screenshot below: 
[image: annotated screenshot] 
(You may need to zoom (or open it in a new tab) a little to see annotations).

This is a ready to be executed request.

Hope this helps.